# MATLAB : passing cell arguments

Tags: matlab

I have a function :

```
function myFunc(myStruct)
    % file can contains one or a list of files
    file = {fullfile(pwd,myStruct.name)}
end
```

from another file , when I call myFunc

```
myStruct.name = {'toto','titi','tata'}
myFunc(myStruct);

I got an error ,function isn't definied for cell
```

and I would like to pass to the field myStruct.name a string or a list of strings :
I mean that myStruct.name can accept one argument 'toto' or list of arguments {'toto','titi'}

When

How could I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want the function to handle that list? What would it return?

Comment: I would just to be able to say myStruct.name can accespt a string or a list of strings

Comment: But "accept" it to do what? For example, an empty function will accept anything as its input!

Comment: @lola: What is the intended output? A list of three subfolders? The subfolder /toto/titi/tata? The subfolder tototititata? Any other combinations of the parameter?

Comment: the feiel of struct myStruct.name could accest a string or a list of strings , I mean from another file when I specify myStruct.name = {'toto",'titi'} then call myFunc(myStruct) , that it works

Comment: @Daniel : the output can be a file or a list of files , it's why I'm looking for a way to give to myStruct.name , one string or a list of strings

Comment: @luis, the function isn't empty ...

Comment: @lola: Louis said that an empty function accepts your input. A trivial solution for your request of a function that accepts cells.

Please fix your question, e.g. the keyword function is missing in the code!

Comment: Report the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we have a complete question.

Read the exception carefully, how you asked your question tells me that you did not understand it. The exception says that `fullfile` is not defined for cell inputs, which is simply fact. You have to call `fullfile` for each folder that should be generated, thus a for-loop is required, with something like `file{idx} = fullfile(pwd,myStruct.name{idx})` in it.